# Auto class importing in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, haxe, haxeflixel

I'm looking to get auto class importing In Sublime Text. I'm using HaxeFlixel and when ever I add a `private var _btnPlay:FlxButton` the needed import doesn't automatically show up. How can I get this to be the default action? Is there maybe a hot key I don't know about?

I know in FlashDevelop it can be done as the [tutorial](http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/groundwork/) I'm following said that was the case:

> We need to define a new `FlxButton` variable to use as our 'play' button. So, type:
>
> `private var _btnPlay:FlxButton;`
> Note: if you're using FlashDevelop, it should automatically create an import for FlxButton (import flixel.ui.FlxButton;) at the top of the class. This should be mostly automatic whenever you use class, but if it doesn't add it for some reason, you can enter it manually, or, highlight FlxButton in the editor and hit Ctrl+Shift+1 to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "Organize Imports" adds missing imports - [here](https://github.com/clemos/haxe-sublime-bundle/pull/193)'s the pull request where this feature was added.

The default shortcut for it requires pressing `Ctrl+Shift+H` and `Ctrl+Shift+O`. You might want to reassign it to something shorter, maybe just `Ctrl+Shift+O`:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+o"], "command": "haxe_organize_imports" }
]
```

Comment: Where do I put that line of code? I can't find a file to edit to add this. I have looked at [link](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key-bindings) but this assumes you know what you are doing.

Comment: `Preferences` -> `Key Bindings - User` opens a file where you can insert it.

Comment: The way you wrote it made more sense to me. On that link those forward slashes made it seem like I was supposed to look in a folder.

Comment: I think that page is in fact talking about a file path - you can get to the Packages folder via `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` There you'll find a `User` subfolder and a `.sublime-keymap` file.